# DB2 seconds of day to readable time

Tags: time, db2

I'm reading an integer field (store open time) that's in seconds of a day, and converting it to something someone would actually be able to read.

Example:
32400 seconds = 9 AM (32400/3600 = 9)

This is fine if every store opens exactly on the hour, but now some stores open and close at the half hour.

Example
9:30 comes back as 9 (34200/3600 = 9), which is not good. I don't want 34200 to come back as 9.5 either.

Ideally I want 32400 to come back as 900 and 34200 to come back as 930, and 46800 to come back as 1300. Both the input and output parameters need to be integers (I can't change column types).

Any easy way to do this in DB2? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple (provided you're using DB2 on Linux, UNIX or Windows):

```
VALUES INT(TIME('00:00:00') + 34200 seconds)/100
```

This will return the desired integer `930` for an input of 34200, and `1300` for an input of 46800.

Comment: +1 for going straight for the `seconds`.  I feel like an idiot for forgetting that (considering what I _did_ put).

Comment: I was just going to make this a comment on your answer, but the OP wanted the results as an INT and not a TIME.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your current data is showing *seconds*, and not *milliseconds* as initially stated...

The following will get you a valid `time` data type in DB2:

```
SELECT CAST('00:00:00' as TIME) + (34200/3600) HOURS + MOD(34200/60, 60) MINUTES
FROM sysibm/sysdummy1
```

After this, translation to a better-readable format is easily handled in your display code.